# Appending Query String To Twig Render Path Function

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a {{ render(path('route')) }} function where I need to append a query string of parameters. How can I do this?

Currently I have this:

```
{{ render(path('page_load', { 'name': name, 'hook': hook ... need to append a dynamic query string ... })) }}
```

And I need to append this query string if defined:

```
{% if queryString is defined and queryString|trim != '' %}?{{ queryString }}{% endif %}
```

**Figured It Out:**

```
{% set string = '' %}
{% if queryString is defined and queryString is not null %}
    {% set string = '?' ~ queryString %}
{% endif %}
    {{ render(path('page_load', { 'name': name, 'hook': hook}) ~ string) }}
```

Answer (score 10):

When using Symfony, you can access the `app.request` global, then you can do something like this:

```
{{ render(path('page_load', app.request.query.all|merge({ 'name': name, 'hook': hook }))) }}
```

Keep in mind that, ideally, you shouldn't store logic in your views.